# Shower Floor Tile - Please Help!

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, remodeling, tiling

We just had glass penny round tile laid on the shower floor yesterday. It is approved for shower floors but we hate the look of it. Since it hasn't been grouted yet, can we pull these up before the thinset hardens? The tiler won't be back for two days and since it's Sunday, we can't ask him or our contractor. Please advise.

Comment: carefully chisel it out, try not to gouge the mudbed under it.

Comment: Jimmy Fix-it, thank you for your input. We've decided we might just keep it, but if not, the tiler will pull it up and fix the waterproofing as necessary.

Comment: If you keep it, perhaps you can make it look more to your tastes by changing the color of the grout. You should be using epoxy grout anyway for a shower, because it is waterproof and very easy to clean, and these are available in a wide range of colors. I mean if you don't like the tiles or their shape, you can make them "disappear" by picking a grout that is the same color.

Answer (score 2):

It will quite possibly ruin the waterproofing layer under the tile. It is best to let it set up, roughen the glossy surface of the tile and set new tile directly over the first.
There will most likely need to be an extension ring added to the drain to get it to the new level.

Comment: Jack, we have a curbless shower or that would be a great solution. I think we've decided to keep this tile because it looks better today in the natural light compared to last evening. If we do decide to change it, the tiler said he'd take it up and fix the waterproofing. At a cost, of course. Hopefully this thread will help someone else in this predicament. I appreciate your input!

Comment: @user133220 If you'll take a moment to take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to any answer that helps you and the check mark next to the one that helped the most.